# Concat strings in CssResource to create a url

Tags: css, gwt

I have some CSS in a ClientBundle that uses a background url. Since I load the javascript (`/MyModule/MyModule.nocache.js`) from `/index.html`, my relative urls in CSS are from root. This means

```
.myBackground { background: url("images/background.png"); }
```

will try to load from `/images/background.png`. This seems like a perfect case for [runtime css substitution](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#Runtime_substitution). I added the following line to the top of my css file:

```
@eval moduleName com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.getModuleName();
```

How do I now combine the `moduleName` variable with the string `"images/background.png"`?

I'm looking for something like:

```
@eval moduleName com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.getModuleName();
.myBackground { background: url(moduleName + "images/background.png"); }
```

Unfortunately, this approach causes some errors in the output during compile:

```
Line 46 column 30: encountered " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER> <PERCENTAGE>
<PT> <MM> <CM> <PC> <IN> <PX> <EMS> <EXS> <DEG> <RAD> <GRAD> <MS> <SECOND> <HZ>
<KHZ> <DIMEN> <FUNCTION>
```

**Note**: I know, there's CSS Sprites, and I'm using that in some places, but I can't get those working correctly in this case because of GWT's extra style information around a CSS sprite conflicting with the extra style stuff I need.

Comment: Would it be possible to just use absolute URLs to the images?

Comment: @jake33, or root-relative paths (`/img/backgroundOne.png`) maybe.

Comment: This CSS is in a library, and the url will be `/gwtModuleName/images/background.png`, with the project using the library defining `gwtModuleName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always add a static function somewhere:

```
public static String getBackgroundUrl(){
     return com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.getModuleName() + "/images/background.png";
}
```

And in your CSS

```
@eval BG_URL com.yourclass.getBackgroundUrl();

.myBackground { background-url:BG_URL; }
```

Comment: I'm giving you the points, because this is a clever hack. It still does mean putting the paths into the code, but atleast it's contained in the module I'm inheriting from.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation...

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "GWT's extra style information around a CSS sprite conflicting with the extra style stuff I need", but if you are referring to additional background properties you need to specify, have you tried splitting up background into it's constituent parts?  E.g., background-image, background-position, [etc](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp).  This recently solved an issue I was having with sprites.